# SwiftUI: Dropping a list row 'into' another list row

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to recreate the drag and drop of rows in the Files app.
So when I drag a list{} row onto another list row, I want it to acknowledge which row it's being dragged over and then be able to execute a function (like entering the row.)

I've tried attaching any .onDrops, but none work.

```
  .onDrop(of: [UTType.content], isTargeted: nil) { _, _ in
    print("Dropped \(header)")}
```

Also a dropdelegate does nothing. It never acknowledges that I want to drop anything at all, it immediately switches over to the onInsert.

A gif of how the built in iPadOS/iOS files app does it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing ! Have you figured out a way to do this yet?

Comment: Yeah I have. I attached a timer to my top view that counts down timeRemaining to 0. Then, using a dropDelegate func dropEntered I reset the counter back to 2 every time I enter a row. Then in the func dropUpdated I call a function when the timeRemaining == 0. That function navigates me to the 'highlighted' row.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly do you want but try to do some digging and check out raywanderlich they have a small article about drag and drop in swiftUI.
I hope you will fix your issue!

https://www.raywenderlich.com/21679742-drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-swiftui